# physics contact delegate not working swift 3 xCode 8

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I can't seem to get my didBegin contact function to work no matter what I do, my spriteNodes are set to dynamic and I'm pretty sure my categoryBitMasks and contactTestBitMasks are correct... Here's the physics part of my code. None of my print commands are getting printed from my didBeginContact function.

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

var theLine = SKSpriteNode()
var fallers = SKSpriteNode()

enum colliderType: UInt32 {

    case theLine = 1
    case fallers = 2
}

override func sceneDidLoad() {

self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    theLine = SKSpriteNode()
    theLine.zPosition = 0
    theLine.size = CGSize(width: 0, height: screenWidth / 128  
    theLine.position = CGPoint(x: midX, y: midY)
    theLine.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: theLine.size)
    theLine.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    theLine.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    theLine.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    theLine.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = colliderType.theLine.rawValue
    theLine.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = colliderType.fallers.rawValue
    theLine.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    addChild(theLine)

fallers[i].size = CGSize(width: 75, height: 75)
fallers[i].color = UIColor.white
fallers[i].alpha = 1
fallers[i].setScale(ds * 4)
fallers[i].zPosition = 9
let fallerTexture = fallers[i].texture
fallers[i].physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: fallerTexture!, size:    fallers[i].size)
fallers[i].physicsBody!.isDynamic = true
fallers[i].physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = colliderType.fallers.rawValue
fallers[i].physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = colliderType.theLine.rawValue
fallers[i].physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = 0
fallers[i].physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false

addChild(fallers[i])

}



func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {


//Detects collisions and what nodes the collisions are between.


if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == colliderType.theLine.rawValue && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == colliderType.fallers.rawValue {

    print("CONTACT")

} else if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == colliderType.fallers.rawValue && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == colliderType.theLine.rawValue {

    print("CONTACT")

    }

}
```

**Update**

I just put an else statement in my didBeginContactDelegate and the code was triggered when the bodies made contact, but the problem is now, is that I can't sort what bodies these contacts are between.

Comment: Put a breakpoint and inspect bodies and their masks to see why no prints are executed.

Comment: What he said. Also put a `print("didBegin: entered")` as the first line of `didBegin` before any of your logic. And this may seem stupid, but are the sprites actually coming into contact on screen?

Comment: It might also be worth setting `showPhysics` to `true` in gameSceneController.swift.

Comment: @Whirlwind  I put an else statement in the contact delegate, and when the two bodies do make contact they set off the code I have in my physics delegate that's in the else statement. So yes they are triggering the contact delegate function to be called but it's not triggering the code I have inside of my expected conditionals.

Comment: @SteveIves ^^Also look at my comment

Comment: @GaardAnderson Take a look at Steve's answer. That would be my preferred way to... Also search SO about how masks works. There are some useful posts...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using simple categories, with each physics body belonging to only one category, then this alternative form of didBeginContact may be more readable:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

    switch contactMask {

    case colliderTytpe.fallers.rawValue | colliderType.theLine.rawValue:
        print("Collision between fallers and theLine")
        let fallersNode = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == colliderTytpe.fallers.rawValue ? contact.bodyA.node! : contact.bodyB.node!

        // Do something with fallersNode
        fallersNode.removeFromParent() // For example
        score += 10 // For example

    default :
        //Some other contact has occurred
        print("Some other contact")
    }
}
```

(If you need to handle other collisions, just add more case blocks to the switch).

It avoids messing about with bodyA and bodyB, and sorting them into order. You only need to deal with them when you have to do something specific with one of the nodes, which is where this line of code comes into play:

```
let fallersNode = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == colliderTytpe.fallers.rawValue ? contact.bodyA.node! : contact.bodyB.node!
```

Which is using Swift's ternary operator to say "if bodyA has faller's category bitMask, then set `fallersNode` to bodyA, else set `fallersNode` to bodyB.

Comment: So I put pretty much this exact code and still, only my default is getting triggered? Also, thank you so much for taking time, I appreciate it a lot!

Comment: So there is some other  contact occurring. Are there any other physics bodies in your scene?

Comment: No, it's just theLine and fallers so far. So I decided to print the bodies' categoryBitMask and it turned out that when the line hits the fallers, fallers is recognized correctly but the other body(theLine), has a category bitmask of 4294967295 for some reason. Even though I set the category bitmask the same way I do the fallers...

Comment: Figured it out... I forgot to mention that in my updateCurrentTime Func, I have theLine.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: theLine.size) so that the physics body will scale with it, but that reset my category bitmasks and everything every frame so I put " theLine.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = colliderType.theLine.rawValue " after it and it now works, I guess now it would be helpful to get a better way to scale my physics body...